# Позиционирование при помощи js/jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Господа, есть div с шириной и высотой 400px в котором есть ещё один div(content).
Мне надо при нажатии кнопки на сайте подвинуть родительский div на 400px влево и при этом заменить div(content) на другой. Как это реализовать при помощи js/jquery? Ещё раз, просто нужно подвинуть блок и поменять контент в нём. Есть мысли? Заранее спасибо.

```
document.getElementById("btn1").onclick = slidel;
document.getElementById("btn2").onclick = slider;
function slidel() {
var move = document.getElementById("signform");
var left = 30;
move.style.left = left + "px";

}

function slider() {
var move = document.getElementById("signform");
var right = 30;
move.style.right = right + "px";
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть ваши наработки?

Comment: О чем тут думать? Надо просто перевести эту фразу на язык JS "при нажатии кнопки на сайте подвинуть родительский div на 400px влево и при этом заменить div(content) на другой"

Comment: Окей, подвинуть удалось, но как быть с контентом? Как мне его сделать? написать всё и дать класс hidden? и после того как поменяю местоположение блока  сделать его visible а тот hidden?Вот видео того, как это должно выглядеть https://vimeo.com/153219852

Comment: ну ... как бы да ...

Comment: Вот js код. Проблема: влево двигается как надо, но вправо вообще не реагирует и в консоли ошибок нету. Код добавил в вопрос.

Comment: С позицией блоков разобрался.

Comment: Всё, господа, судоку решено))) Всем, спасибо